# Foreign key between tbls

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity, code-first

i create Table with Code First and create table with fluentapi .

how can i create Foreign key between them ?

```
    public partial class Tbl_Gender
{
    [Key]
    public int GendID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public GenType GendType { get; set; }
}
public enum GenType
{
    Male = 1,
    Fmale = 2
}
```

}
.

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.AspNetUsers",
            c => new
            {
                Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                Name = c.String(),
                Family = c.String(),
                UserPhoto = c.String(),
                RoleID = c.String(),
                Gender = c.String(),
                Email = c.String(maxLength: 256),
                EmailConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                PasswordHash = c.String(),
                SecurityStamp = c.String(),
                PhoneNumber = c.String(),
                PhoneNumberConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                TwoFactorEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                LockoutEndDateUtc = c.DateTime(),
                LockoutEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                AccessFailedCount = c.Int(nullable: false),
                UserName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .Index(t => t.UserName, unique: true, name: "UserNameIndex");
```

/*******************************************************************************/

Comment: Perhaps this tutorial can help: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Though I would not use that table structure for Gender - why not stick Gender enum directly on ApplicationUser table?